# XML incremental parsing with python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm trying to parse a huge XML file with the code below and whenever I run the code through the terminal, it's just run without any errors and does nothing. I need it to parse the file incrementally and delete the parent element after checking if Submission time is older than a specific number of days.

For example, the XML structure is like this:

```
<Feed>
<Reviews>
<Review>
<SubmissionTime>2015-06-16T19:00:00.000-05:00</SubmissionTime>
</Review>
</Reviews
</Feed>
```

```
from lxml import etree, objectify
import logging, sys, iso8601
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import re




def remove_per_age(file):
    datestring = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
    full_data = ""
    for event, elem in ET.iterparse(sys.argv[1], events=("end",)):
        if elem.tag == 'SubmissionTime':
            element_datetime = iso8601.parse_date(elem.text)
            element_date = element_datetime.date()
            if (element_date < datetime.now(element_datetime.tzinfo).date()-relativedelta(days=180)):
                elem.getparent().remove(elem)
            else:
                full_data += ET.tostring(elem)
        else:
            elem.clear()
    with open("output.xml", 'w') as f:
        f.write(full_data)
        
def strip_tag_name(tag):
    pattern = re.compile(r'\{.+\}')
    clean_tag = pattern.sub(r'', tag)
    return clean_tag

if __name__ == "__main__":
   remove_per_age(sys.argv[1])

#Reviews/Review/SubmissionTime
```

Answer (score -1):

The way to handle huge XML file incrementally is to use [SAX](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/xml.sax.html).
You will need to extend `xml.sax.ContentHandler` and add your logic there.
See https://www.tutorialspoint.com/parsing-xml-with-sax-apis-in-python for an example

Comment: This might be better as a comment than an answer.

Comment: @Parfait What would you consider as an answer here? Implementing the logic inside the SAX content handler? I consider the above as an answer since it points the OP to a clear direction.

Comment: This does not answer OP's main issue: *whenever I run the code through the terminal, it's just run without any errors and does nothing*. Technically, you are recommending a different library to *handle huge XML*.